# Extraer dato especifico de un string usando Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

Tengo un problema, al anterior desarrollador se le ocurrio meter `html` dentro de las columnas de una tabla `mysql` el cual viene con el formato siguiente:

```
:::: colString :::::
<area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="comunicados/pdf/archivo09218-231dXM.pdf" coords="6,6,798,1030" shape="rect">
```

Utilizando `Laravel` como seria para extraer solamente el `href` del String anterior.

```
$data = DB::table('data')->get();
foreach($data as $value){
   $colString = $value->colString; //<area target="_blank"...
}
```

¿Alguna recomendación, como lo harían ustedes? Independientemente de si es a traves de laravel o utilizando código `SQL` directamente en la tabla.

Comment: laravel o sql o lo que sea, probaste con un substring?

Comment: No, ¿Cómo sería un ejemplo aplicado?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php es la documentacion de substr en php ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes utilizar expresiones regulares mediante [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php) para obtener lo que está dentro del `href="..."`.

```php
$data = DB::table('data')->get();

foreach ($data as $value) {
    $colString = $value->colString;
    preg_match('/href="(.*?)"/', $colString, $matches);
    // Si no hay coincidencia guarda un string vacío
    $href = $matches[1] ?? ''; // comunicados/pdf/archivo09218-231dXM.pdf
}
```

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/tjXwNc/1)